# find the max ID in Ms-access Db vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

i want to find the max ID in my Ms-access db !
im trying to do that with this simple code but i got error because is datatable and cannot converted to string !
how to solve this ?

```
Dim dt As DataTable = New DBConnect().selectdata(String.Format("SELECT MAX(id) AS LastId FROM StockTable"))
MsgBox(dt.ToString)
```

the function :

```
Public Function selectdata(ByVal cmdtext As String) As DataTable
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    With cmd
        .CommandText = cmdtext
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .Connection = con
    End With
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    da.Fill(dt)
    Return dt
End Function
```

Comment: [OleDbCommand.ExecuteScalar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the row and field name you're accessing...

```
MsgBox(dt.ToString)
```

This should be...

```
MsgBox(dt.Rows(0)("LastId").ToString)
```